# How do I fix sitemap errors?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, xml-sitemap, gatsby-plugin

Sitemap Doesn't work
I can't get the site map URL and I can't use the /sitemap.xml URL
How do I fix it??

```
  siteMetadata: {
    siteUrl: siteAddress.href, // which is "https://www.example.com/"
  },
 {
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
  options: {
    head: true,
    output: `/sitemap.xml`,
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain in more technical terms than "Doesn't work"?

Comment: I can't get URL of the sitemap and I don't know why

Comment: We can't help with "doesn't work". We can help with *specific errors* or technical problems you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried building your project? [From the docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-sitemap/):

> *NOTE: This plugin only generates output when run in production mode! To test your sitemap, run: `gatsby build && gatsby serve`*

In addition, your plugin's options are not valid: `head` should be `createLinkInHead`. A full sample with queries should look like:

```
 {
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
    options: {
      output: `/some-other-sitemap.xml`,
      createLinkInHead: true,
      exclude: [`/category/*`, `/path/to/page`],
      query: `
        {
          wp {
            generalSettings {
              siteUrl
            }
          }

          allSitePage {
            nodes {
              path
            }
          }
      }`,
      resolveSiteUrl: ({site, allSitePage}) => {
        return site.wp.generalSettings.siteUrl
      },
      serialize: ({ site, allSitePage }) =>
        allSitePage.nodes.map(node => {
          return {
            url: `${site.wp.generalSettings.siteUrl}${node.path}`,
            changefreq: `daily`,
            priority: 0.7,
          }
        })
    }
  }
```

Alternatively, you can use [`gatsby-plugin-advanced-sitemap`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-advanced-sitemap) which has more customizable options.